# Computing Poincare map for positive x-Axis

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**PROBLEM:** The vector field $f(x, y) = (−y, x)$ has the periodic solution
$(\cos(t), \sin(t))$. Compute the Poincare map corresponding to $$\sum = \{(x, y) ∈ \mathbb{R}^2|x > 0, \; \: y = 0\}$$

**SOLUTION FROM STACK:** [Poincaré map corresponding to submanifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290071/poincar%c3%a9-map-corresponding-to-submanifold)

**MY QUESTION:** I understand, that the integral curves for the map are concentric circles $\{(r\cos(t),r\sin(t))∣t∈R\}$ for $r > 0.$ But I am supposed to adjust this simple solution to the following notation.

[image]